# Building a Tree with MYSQL on Web

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tree

I am trying with JSF + Primefaces to use a list of data that I retrieve from MySQL to build a Tree widget. My problem being that  I don't know how make the Tree.

I have this data in my MySQL as an example:

```
   id   |       name      | class_id | fl_id
-----------------------------------------------
    1   |    MARKETING    |    0     |   1
    2   |   COMMERCIAL    |    0     |   1
    3   | TRADE-MARKETING |    1     |   1
    4   |      SALES      |    1     |   1
    5   |     RICHARD     |    1     |   2
    6   |      ROGER      |    1     |   3
    7   |      MARIA      |    2     |   4
```

Which should result in a tree display similar to:

```
MARKETING
   >TRADE MARKETING
   >RICHARD
      >>ROGER
COMMERCIAL
   >SALES
MARIA
```

As you notice, from the class id, the parent are 0 and the child are 1 (Which I observe is usually null for the father, but I can't change my database).

What I have coded so far is similar to this:

```
// Connection with MySQL, get result set, put all the data in my list and use a loop
// to count on that list. Then use an "if" condition to tell if 1 or 0, as child or
// father
for(count = 0, cont < rs.getString("class id").size(); count++)
    if(rs.getInt("class id") == 1) {
    }
    else if(rs.getInt("class id") == 2) {
    }
}
// Basically is wrong, because I can't tell what is the end, or leaf.
```

Basically its code that Ive conceptualized but not fully tested yet. I could post all the code, but I can't log in at work (somehow blocks it).

I've researched every page on Google I could find to find out how to do this, but it's pretty confusing how to make a tree with MySQL, by far static display is much simpler (from example on Primefaces). I am just a beginner in Java.

Comment: No spaces in column names AFAIK, class id is not valid identifier.

Comment: i know, it's just view of my table

Comment: How deep will the tree go?

Comment: Hm... For example that i gave from Roger, It might have more 2-3 levels.

Comment: How are you tracking the relationship between parent and children? For example, how are you determining that Roger is a child of Richard?

Comment: If it's not too deep you can self join to get the relationships. But that assumes you have a max depth. Otherwise you'll have to reassemble via Java. Why is Maria on the top level?

Comment: @ethrbunny, Perception made some changes that i didn't notice. But still an example and I think you got the ideia what my problem is.

Comment: @Callum, Im tracking with the id, id class and fl class together doing relationship with statement.

Comment: @iwamoto Is your tree example accurate? "Trade Marketing" and "Sales" have the same class_id and fl_id, yet they both appear under a different parent in the example.

Comment: @Callum, Hmmm i thought i put the fix on my comment, so Trade and Sales are 2 on fl_class, Richard is 3, Roger is 4 and Maria is 5.